# How to reserve range of ids in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, locking, bulkinsert

I've to perform a bulk insert of many records with associated records (has_many table).
So my strategy is this:

build a raw SQL query specifying consecutive ids (primary key) so the associated records can be built with these ids as foreign key values.
But I need to prevent that other concurrency connections creates a new record with the id in the range that I need to use to the bulk query.
How can I reserve a range of ids for the bulk insert?
I've tried to use `alter table tablename auto_increment = x` but does not work.
Also, I've tried to create a fake record with this query:

```
LOCK TABLES tablename WRITE
# get last id (for example 100)
INSERT INTO tablename (SELECT 201 AS id, name FROM tablename WHERE id = 100)
UNLOCK TABLES
```

But this does not work cause I get the error `tablename was not locked with LOCK TABLES`.

Any idea to solve this problem?

I hope I explained myself :D

Comment: Do not reserve. INSERT into main table. Then INSERT associated records into slave with SELECT according IDs from main table.

Comment: @Akina interesting, but how can I select the ids? They are autoincremented and I don't know how to retrieve the records inserted with the bulk query.

Comment: In bulk insertion insert the data for both tables into temporary table then copy to working tables.

Comment: That insert-select could be turned into an `UPDATE` unless you want a second row.  Also, if you are using InnoDB, don't even consider `LOCK/UNLOCK TABLES`.

Answer (score 0):

Schematically:

```
INSERT INTO main (fields except ID) 
VALUES (literal values for fields);

INSERT INTO slave (main_id, other fields except ID)
SELECT id, (literal values for other fields)
FROM main
WHERE (fields from main except ID) = (literal values for main fields);
```

---

For bulk insert you must use an intermediate table which accepts the data for both main and slave(s), and after insert into it you copy the data into separate tables with assigning proper referential values.

> ```
> -- working tables
> CREATE TABLE main (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
>                    main_val INT);
> CREATE TABLE slave (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
>                     slave_val INT,
>                     id_main BIGINT UNSIGNED,
>                     FOREIGN KEY (id_main) REFERENCES main(id));
> ```

> ```
> -- table for bulk insert
> CREATE TABLE for_bulk_insert ( main_val INT, slave_val INT );
> -- data for bulk insert, in practice it is loaded using LOAD DATA INFILE
> INSERT INTO for_bulk_insert VALUES (11,111), (22,222), (33,333);
> ```

> ```
> -- insert data into main table
> INSERT INTO main (main_val)
> SELECT main_val FROM for_bulk_insert;
> ```

> ```
> -- insert data into slave table with referenced values from main table
> INSERT INTO slave (slave_val, id_main)
> SELECT for_bulk_insert.slave_val, main.id
> FROM for_bulk_insert
> JOIN main ON for_bulk_insert.main_val = main.main_val;
> ```

> ```
> -- check the result
> SELECT * FROM main;
> SELECT * FROM slave;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | main_val
> -: | -------:
>  1 |       11
>  2 |       22
>  3 |       33
>
> id | slave_val | id_main
> -: | --------: | ------:
>  1 |       111 |       1
>  2 |       222 |       2
>  3 |       333 |       3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c6a86259e6dec1ebc9e84d84eaa81c7a)*

Of course the data array inserted into main (in shown example it is one field `main_val`) must be unique over the table.